# PHP SMB File upload is successful but returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, file-upload, fopen

When I try to upload a file from a local folder on pc to the ftp server via SMB the file gets uploaded, however the server returns a 500 Internal Server Error with the following message:

> Warning: fopen(File.xls): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This is my function for the upload:

```
public function upload($fileToUpload, $targetPath = "") {
    if (!empty($targetPath)) {
        if (substr($targetPath, -1, 1) != '/') {
            $targetPath .= "/";
        }
    }

    $fileName = basename($fileToUpload);
    $this->srvShare->put($fileToUpload, $targetPath . $fileName);
}
```

**$fileToUpload** in this case is something like 'File.xls'.
I already tried to give the function the whole path. But it still results in the same error.
The upload does work.. the file is on the server but the code can't proceed since it's still resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error.

This is the put() function from smb NativeShare:

```
/**
 * Upload a local file
 *
 * @param string $source local file
 * @param string $target remove file
 * @return bool
 *
 * @throws \Icewind\SMB\Exception\NotFoundException
 * @throws \Icewind\SMB\Exception\InvalidTypeException
 */
public function put($source, $target) {
    $sourceHandle = fopen($source, 'rb');
    $targetUrl = $this->buildUrl($target);
    $targetHandle = $this->getState()->create($targetUrl);
    while ($data = fread($sourceHandle, NativeReadStream::CHUNK_SIZE)) {
        $this->getState()->write($targetHandle, $data, $targetUrl);
    }
    $this->getState()->close($targetHandle, $targetUrl);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's there in web-server logs?

Comment: @Jared - The server log is the following: CRITICAL
08:29:15
request Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Warning: fopen(File.xls): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" at /var/www/servername/httpdocs/import/practice/import/vendor/icewind/smb/src/Native/NativeShare.php line 199
{
    "exception": {}
}

And this error refers to the put() function

Comment: What means your source File.xls is missing. Check the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Alright.. so I was able to fix the error.
The problem was that I already had this upload function somewhere being used and I assumed I can use it just again with the same parameters.. I needed to change on parameter and now it works :)